# The minimum of difference between the arithmetic averages of elements of subsets

Tags: inequality, graph-theory

**question**

Let $n$ be a natural number greater than $2$, $k$ a strictly positive real number and $M=(1, 2, \dots, n)$. We associate each nonempty subset of $M$ with a distinct point in the plane and for any two subsets distinct, if the arithmetic averages of its elements differ by at most $k$, we join the points associated with them through a segment.

Determine the minimum value of $k$ such that the points associated with any two different nonempty subsets of the set $M$ are joined by a segment or broken line.

**my idea**

Using the formula we get that there are $2^n$ subsets. We need nonempty ones so there are $2^n-1$ of subsets that we are gonna analise.

I think we have the use the fact that thr numners are consecutive and that we are gonna calculate their aritmetic mean. Maybe we will use the inequality of the means.

I dont know where to start. Hope one of you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Where does the broken line come from?

Comment: @user:  I think the broken line is a path of the line segments.  OP is asking for the minimum $k$ that makes the graph connected.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thats right!

Comment: @RossMillikan Is the absence of a segment a broken line?

Comment: Hint:  what is the minimum value of the average of a subset?  What is the next smallest value?  Now argue that difference is the $k$ you want.

Comment: @user:  we have a vertex of the graph for each subset.  OP has given a rule for which pairs of vertices are connected by edges depending on $k$.  The question is the minimum $k$ for which the graph is connected.  If points $a,b$ are connected and $b,c$ are connected but $a,c$ are not connected by an edge we say $a$ and $c$ are connected by a broken line.

Comment: @RossMillikan is the minimum value of the average of a subset $\frac{n*(n+1)}{4}$

Comment: No, that is not correct.  Think about small subsets.

Comment: @RossMillikan Now I see: the requirement is that any two points are connected by some path consisting of the segments. Is it correct?

Comment: @user:  yes, that is correct

Comment: Hint: prove that the maximum of the differences between an average and those nearest to it is always $1/2$.

Comment: @RossMillikan I dont really understand what do you mean by small subsets

Comment: Subsets with rather few members

Comment: Ignore the question of differences in means for the moment. Given any two subsets, can you figure out a sequence of subsets connecting them such that any two neighboring sets in the sequence differ in only one number, and those two numbers are only $1$ apart (including if the neighbors differ only in one set containing the number $1$ while the other does not)?

Comment: Consider a subset that is an extremal one (either maximum or minimum) in sense of average value. What is that subset? What is the closest other subset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem formulation is overcomplicated. To simplify and clarify the problem consider the set $A$ of arithmetic means of nonempty subsets of $M$. Let $(a_1,\dots,a_m)$ be the enumeration of $A$ in the increasing order.
It is easy to see that the problem requirement holds iff the difference between each two consecutive
members of $A$ is at most $k$. Clearly, $a_1=1$, and it is easy to check that the arithmetic mean of
any subset $S\ne\{1\}$ of $A$ is at least $\frac 32$, and the equality is attained when $S=\{1,2\}$.
Thus $a_2=\frac 32$ and so $k\ge\frac 12$.

On the other hand, $k=\frac 12$ suffices to satisfy the problem requirement. Indeed, arithmetic means of
all one-element subsets of $M$ belong to $A$, so $A\supset\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Moreover, arithmetic means of subsets of $M$ consisting of two consecutive numbers of $M$ belong to $A$ to, so $A\supset\left\{\frac {1+2}2,\frac {2+3}2,\dots,\frac {2n-1}2\right\}$. Each remaining element of $A$ is between some two of the above elements of $A$, whose difference is $\frac 12$.

Comment: Thank you so much for you idea. I have one question: how can i demonstrate that each remaining element of A is between some two of the above elements ?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Each (remaining) element of $A$ belongs to the segment $[\min M,\max M]$ that is, to the segment $[1,n]$.
The already found elements of $A$ partition this segment into small segments of length $\frac 12$. So any
(remaining) element $a$ of $A$ is contained is one of these small segments, thus the distance from $a$ to any endpoint of this segment is at most $\frac 12$.